# quick question about posets using inclusion

Tags: order-theory

Let $X$ be a collection of sets that is partially ordered by inclusion ($\subseteq$). I think I know that answer to this(I think it is yes), but are the linearly ordered subsets of $X$ must always have an upper bound? So, I can just always us Zorn's lemma for any set that partially ordered by inclusion

Comment: A linearly ordered subset of $X$ need not have an upper bound in $X$. There will always be an upper bound outside $X$, but that doesn't let you apply Zorn's lemma. And $X$ need not have a maximal element; for example, $X$ could be the collection of all finite subsets of $\mathbb  N$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Could you give an example with the collection of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$? I can only think of linearly order subcollections. As an example, $\{\{1,2,3\},\{1,2\},\{1\}\}\$. Also, I am only talking about when the partially ordering is a subset.

Comment: If you don't stop at $3$ in your example but include, in your linearly ordered set, all the sets of the form $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ for all natural numbers $n$, you'll have a linearly ordered (by $\subseteq$) subcollection of my $X$ with no upper bound in $X$.